# EF Models Class With another Partial Class, The Partial class's Property's value is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is EF Models class, Auto generate.

```
namespace MySys.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class CustomerInfo
{
    public System.Guid CustomerInfoID { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is My partial class

```
public partial class CustomerInfo
{
    public string CustomerType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> OperatorUserID { get; set; }
}
```

But When I used this code to get list, the value of CustomerType is null.

```
List<CustomerInfo> CustomerInfoList = new List<CustomerInfo>(db.Database.SqlQuery<CustomerInfo>("EXEC usp_GetCustomerInfoList @PageSize,@PageIndex,@WhereStr,@OrderbyStr,@TotalRecord output", param_pagesize, param_pageindex, param_wherestring, param_orderstr, param_totalrecord));
```

Anyone can tell me how to do it correct?
The two files is in the same assemblies.
Thanks.

Comment: The problem is most likely your stored procedure. Post the code for that.

Comment: My store procedure will execute this sql statement:
select * from (select row_number() over (order by a.CreateDate desc) as rowId, 
a.*,b.[TypeValue] as CustomerType from  CustomerInfo a left join [CodeMaster] b on a.CustomerTypeID=b.[ID] 
where a.DelFlag='N') as t where rowId between 31 and 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial class is used to extend the entity type and those properties will be ignored during query.

You can try creating a derived type instead.

```
public partial class CustomerInfo
{
    public string CustomerType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> OperatorUserID { get; set; }
}
public class CustomCustomerInfo : CustomerInfo {}
```

And map the query to the derived type.

```
SqlQuery<CustomCustomerInfo>("EXEC usp_GetCustomerInfoList ...")
```